# How to link css to razor page (asp.net core)

Tags: css, asp.net-core, razor

I don't know how to link css to razor page, nothing works. Heres my folder structure:

```
Views/Home/index.cshtml

wwwroot/Styles/Homepage.css
```

Answer (score 1):

For CSS that are reused among the entire site you can define them in the  section of the _Layout:

```
<head>
    <link href="/Styles/Homepage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @RenderSection("Styles", required: false)
</head>
```

and if I need some view specific styles you can define the Styles section in each view:

```
@section Styles {
    <link href="~/Styles/Homepage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
```